# ZTIDrivers Type Mismatch in MDT during Task Sequence

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mdt

I'm trying to deploy Windows 10 to a lenovo laptop using MDT.  I have a selection profile for this particular Task Sequence that selects only the drivers for this model.  The drivers I imported was the complete driver pack for SCCM that you can download from Lenovo, so all the drivers were inf and cab.

Right at the step where it injects, I get the error below, and the TS fails before the OS starts to install.

```
ZTI ERROR - Unhandled error returned by ZTIDrivers: Type mismatch (13)  ZTIDrivers  11/2/2021 3:37:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
Event 41002 sent: ZTI ERROR - Unhandled error returned by ZTIDrivers: Type mismatch (13)    ZTIDrivers  11/2/2021 3:37:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
Command completed, return code = -2147467259    LiteTouch   11/2/2021 3:37:36 PM    0 (0x0000)
Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code = -2147467259  0x80004005  LiteTouch   11/2/2021 3:37:36 PM    0 (0x0000)
Event 41014 sent: Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code = -2147467259  0x80004005    LiteTouch   11/2/2021 3:37:36 PM    0 (0x0000)
```

Some things I have checked:

- The GUID of the OS and the GUID in the tasksequence XML match
- Tried reimporting the drivers, and reimporting the OS wim
- Tried using the same TS, but with vanilla Windows 10 21H1 for the image.

Why am I getting that error?  Nothing I've searched yields anything that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same error recently.  We use external USB media for our MDT build deployment.
This is what I found caused this error in my case.

The OSGUID variable was not getting set to a valid value.

To figure this out I first looked at the ZTIDriver.wsf script.
In the ZTIDrivers.wsf script, up near the top, it will parse the envirVar "ImageBuild" to come up the the local variable "sTargetBuild".

If "ImageBuild" is null, then the local "sTargetBuild" variable won't get set properly.  More on this in a bit.

Later in the ZTIDrivers.wsf script, in the "Function UpdateConfiguration", the sTargetBuild value is checked ("If sTargetBuild <> 5 then").  Since sTargetBuild isn't set properly (I suspect that it is null), it doesn't match the proper data type for the IF evaluation.  So it coughs up the "Type Mismatch" error.

OK, back to the "ImageBuild" variable.  Why is this null or not set?
On a previous successful deployed build, I check the BDD.log from the deployment and search for "ImageBuild".   I search for "ImageBuild" and find that it is being set ("Property ImageBuild is now = 10.0.19041.1469").

I check the BDD.log on the failed "Type Mismatch" system.
There is no mention of "ImageBuild".

Back in the successful BDD.log, a few lines above where the "ImageBuild" is seen, I see the "OSGUID" value displayed ("Property OSGUID is now = (a899bc.....").

When I look for this "OSGUID" line in the failed BDD.log, I do see a similar line ("Property OSGUID is now = {388c2ee4-....").
BUT I also see a line just below it that says "ERROR:  Invalid OS GUID {388c2ee4-....".

Where did it get this invalid OSGUID from?
While my TS.XML has the correct GUID listed for the "Install Operating System" task (and that valid GUID is set for the OS in the OperatingSystems.xml),  I also see that way up at the top of the TS.XML, in the "globalVarList" section, there are additional lines where OSGUID is set.  AND it is getting set to the invalid value that is listed in BDD.log.

For some reason in my TS.XML in the "globalVarList" section, I have two OSGUID value entries.   Not sure why multiple.

But my fix was to manually edit the TS.XML and change the invalid OSGUID entries so that they were using the valid GUID for the OS.

Hope this helps.